# Як правильно перекласти слово «Playboy»?

Tags: переклад, from-english, значення-слів, іменники

Засновником «Playboy» вважається Х'ю Хефнер. Однак як саме правильно перекласти цю назву?

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playboy) подає лише інформацію, однак без чіткого перекладу слова:

> **Playboy** (англ.) («Плейбо́й») — це американський чоловічий лайф-стайл журнал розважального характеру.

Comment: Вас цікавить: як власну назву журналу чи як загальну назва? Бо назви журналів зазвичай не перекладають.

Comment: загальна назва, адже, ймовірно, власна назва пішла від загальної.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В  [«Словнику іншомовних слів» за ред. О.С.Мельничука 1974 р.](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/Dynamichni_procesy.pdf) знаходимо:

> Вихідне значення англ. **play-boy** *«гульвіса, бенкетар, байда»*. Російська розмовна практика фіксує нині й похідне від цього запозичення слово *плейбойчик* – відповідник іншого значення англійського етимона – назви (у британському
>   слензі) пігулок наркотика екстезі із зображенням логотипа журналу «Плейбой» – потішного зайчика.